# Subgroup of GL(3,$\mathbb{C}$) generated by two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying on subgroups of GL(3,$\mathbb{C}$) generated by two matrices. But I'm a complete novice of this topic with some basic linear algebra and abstract algebra. Is there a field dealing with this sort of topic?

More specifically, I'm interested in the computational aspects of the subgroup, i.e., traces, determinants, eigenvalues, and related polynomials. How much can I say about the eigenvalues or traces of AB, the product of two known matrices A and B, by using the information given by only A and B?

Comment: One way to put what you are doing is: you are looking at the three dimensional representations of the free group on two generators. Thus one field which deals with your topic is the representation theory of groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is representation theory of groups and related topics in topology and differential geometry, e.g., [stable multiplicities in the length spectrum of Riemannian surfaces](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.tau.ac.il%2F~rudnick%2Fpapers%2Fginzburg-rudnick.pdf&ei=T_-sVP3PNITYPIqGgagP&usg=AFQjCNGdjsEhjmLH6QCKoM9scsqrBfOa7A&bvm=bv.83134100,d.ZWU) . Trace polynomials of words in $A$ and $B$ have been intensively studied, in particular for two-dimensional complex representations $\langle A,B\rangle \rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. The question here is how to describe the trace classes of words $w(A,B)$, i.e., having the same trace. For example $w(A,B)$ and $w^{-1}(A,B)$ always have the same trace. So do conjugate words. Interestingly, also reading a word backwards has always the same trace, i.e., ${\rm tr}(A^{r_1}B^{m_1}\cdots A^{r_n}B^{m_n})={\rm tr}(B^{m_n}A^{r_n}\cdots B^{m_1}A^{r_1}) $ for all $A,B\in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Is this basically all you can do ?

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!